# Download file from cloud disk (S3) with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, download

I'm having some problems generating a file download response in Laravel 5.1 while trying to download a file from Amazon S3.

This is my controller action:

```
/**
 * @param GetRequest $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function get(GetRequest $request)
{
    $fileEntry = $this->fileRepository->find();
    $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get('projects/'.$fileEntry->project.'/'.$fileEntry->name);

    return $this->respondDownload($file, $fileEntry->name, $fileEntry->type);
}
```

And this is the `respondDownload` method:

```
/**
 * Respond with a file download.
 *
 * @param $fileContent
 * @param $fileName
 * @param $mime
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function respondDownload($fileContent, $fileName, $mime)
{
    return (new Response($fileContent, 200))
        ->header('Content-Type', $mime)
        ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
}
```

If I open the developer tools I can see that the response is successful and the content is set to the file content, but the browser is not prompting to save the file somewhere.

How can I solve this problem? Is something wrong with the headers?

**Edit**

I also tried making a streamed response but the browser is still not showing a save file modal.

```
public function respondDownload($fileContent, $fileName, $mime)
{
    return (new StreamedResponse(function() use ($fileContent)
    {
        echo $fileContent;
    }, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => $mime,
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"'
    ]));
}
```

**Edit 2**

Response headers:
[image: Response headers]

Response content:
[image: Response content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was caused by how I sent the download request to the server.

Previously I was making an AJAX request to the server and that wasn't making the browser to prompt me where to save the downloaded file.

In order to fix that I simply had to start the download request from an `a` tag.

Comment: Hey, i'm having a similar problem. Could you post your AJAX request? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sending any AJAX request, just made a link pointing to the route handling the downloads. For example: `http://localhost/file/193/download`

Comment: What helper did you use? the route()  ?

Comment: No helpers at all because the UI is totally detached from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `Response()` object without specifiying to download it. Try this instead:

```
public function respondDownload($fileContent, $fileName, $mime)
{
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => $mime, 
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment',
        'filename'=>$fileName
    ];
    return response()->download($fileContent, $fileName, $headers);
}
```

Comment: This is causing a server error: *exception 'ErrorException' with message 'is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given'* Guess because the `download()` method expects a file path, not the file's content.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought it would be the file path. If you change it to the file instead of the contents it should work. @siannone

Comment: The problem is that I can't do that because the file is located on S3 so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Can't you save it locally until it is downloaded? But it should be even possible by specifying the remote path on your s3 disc and pass that to the download function. I have a custom dropbox storage provider that handles it just this way. @siannone

Comment: I tried to make the changes you suggested, by saving the file on the server first and then downloading it but i still get the same issue. The file content is returned with the response but the browser is not displaying any file save modal.

Comment: Are you sure that the request headers like $mime are correct?

Comment: I just added the response headers as I see them in the browser to the question. As you can see the **Content-Type** is set correctly. Do you think that the fact that the client side is running a single page application could influence it?